# font distorted when resizing it with animation

Tags: html, css, animation, fonts

I change the size of a div (including the sub divs and other elements) when user hovers over it. I noticed that the font gets distorted when doing so. This doesn't happen on a mac, but it does on windows machines. This is the code for hover animation and coresponidng HTML (I choped out the irrelevant parts):

```
   CSS: @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

    .content-no-btn { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }

    .content-no-btn:hover{ transform: scale(1.05); }

HTML:
  <div class="plan">
    <div class="plan-inner">
        <div class="content-no-btn">

          <div class="entry-title first-entry-title">
            <h3>H3 here </h3>
            <div class="price">$23.99<span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle which reproduces your problem. Also, does it occurs only in a particular browser or all the browsers. In mac did you check it on all the browser (I am assuming that you might be using safari)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very nicely explained by Zoltan in [this](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/) blog post 
This problem arises due to CSS transfrom property because of which the text is rendered with jagged edges as shown in the image below.

[image: Jagged Edges due to transform property]

(This image is taken from Zoltan blog)

This effect is more visible in Windows and hardly noticeable in Mac.

**Solution**

There are various solution to this problem, however  i prefer to add [prespective](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/) to transfrom property.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

    .content-no-btn { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }

    .content-no-btn:hover{ 
      transform: perspective(1px) scale(1.1);
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="plan">
    <div class="plan-inner">
        <div class="content-no-btn">

          <div class="entry-title first-entry-title">
            <h3>H3 here </h3>
            <div class="price">$23.99<span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Another solution is to use SVG [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and [backface-visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility) property

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

    .content-no-btn { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }

    .content-no-btn:hover{ 
      transform: scale(1.1);
      transform-origin: 0 0;
       /*For chrome or other WebKit/Blink browsers.*/
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

      /*For Firefox */
      filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><filter id="gaussian_blur"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" /></filter></defs></svg>#gaussian_blur');

    }
```

```html
<div class="plan">
    <div class="plan-inner">
        <div class="content-no-btn">

          <div class="entry-title first-entry-title">
            <h3>H3 here </h3>
            <div class="price">$23.99<span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In my Linux machine second solution is working perfectly.

I hope that solves your problem.